# Deshabilitar CORS Laravel

Tags: laravel, cors

Como puedo deshabilitar completamente los CORS en `Laravel`

> El permiso de notificación solo se puede solicitar desde un controlador de eventos generados por el usuario de ejecución corta. psiquicas
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://jdc.firstimageproducts.com/public/api/carta. (Reason: header ‘x-csrf-token’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).

**Reason: header ‘x-csrf-token’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response**

> Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://jdc.firstimageproducts.com/public/api/carta. (Razón: Solicitud CORS no exitosa).

He intentado con el siguiente código pero no funciona, he incluso con todas su combinatorias posibles, pero nada.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir un middleware ejecutándose para todos los eventos que necesites remover CORS, este de ir asi

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
    }
```

Comment: igual continua bloqueando,

Answer (score 0):

Deshabilita la carga del middleware para los CORS, comentando la línea, en "app/Http/Kernel.php".

En Laravel 7 y 8:

```
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

En Laravel 9 y 10:

```
\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
```

De cualquier modo, ***no es recomendable desactivar este u otros sistemas de seguridad*** que trae el framework.

Opcionalmente, prueba a jugar con la configuración de CORS, en ["config/cors.php"](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/cors.php).